# Pair a bluetooth mouse directly with Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I have Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse, which has a dedicated Bluetooth receiver USB dongle. When I plug it in on the left-hand side of the laptop and the mouse is physically on the right-hand side of the laptop, there is some kind of interference and the mouse does not work, it only works when the mouse is physically on the left-hand side of the laptop, closer to the dongle.
Is there a way to pair the mouse directly with the built-in Bluetooth in the Macbook Air so I don't have to use the USB dongle?
It is Macbook Air 13" 2020, and Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse.

Comment: It does not work when plugged in on the left, but works when plugged in on the left??? Must change what I smoke.

Comment: The USB dongle can be only plugged on the left-hand side of the laptop. If the mouse is physically on the left-hand side of the laptop too, it works. If the mouse is physically on the right-hand side of the laptop, the mouse does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The mouse has a fixed connection to the dongle, you can not use a normal bluetooth connection
- Once the bluetooth dongle fails or you lose it, you can't simply buy a new dongle, since you are unable to pair the mouse to it again. This means once you will end up with a useless mouse

Note: You have to dig a little deeper into the reviews/questions for example [here on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B00D68ZVY8/1/ref=ask_ql_psf_ql_hza?language=de_DE&isAnswered=true&askLanguage=en_US) to verify that you can not buy dongle replacements

Comment: I have found that (at least) Logitech sell replacement dongles that work with any of their mice or keyboards. That **may** indicate that Microsoft might also sell replacement dongles. Just guessing here.

Comment: I am aware of that since I actually had to buy a new dongle for my MX Master after losing the original one. Yet, as I clearly state, you can **not** do this with this Microsoft mouse. I will add a source.